# Use combobox to change all pivot tables' filter simultaneously in one selection (Excel VBA code)

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, pivot-table

I am working with Excel and I currently have these multiple Pivot Tables in one sheet (Sheet2) that I am trying to control with combo boxes as filters in Sheet1.
So basically what I want to have the selection from the ComboBox in Sheet1 to filter all the Pivot Tables in Sheet2 (around 10 or so).

Now I seem to be able to use VBA to achieve this in a new file with only ONE pivot table, but upon applying it to my real-working sheets, it kept on giving me error messages.

Here's the code that I used to manage successfully:

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim QtrChosen As String

    QtrChosen = Worksheets("Database").Range("C3").Value

    MsgBox QtrChosen

    Dim PivotTable10 As PivotTable

    Worksheets("PivotTable").PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields("Qtr").ClearAllFilters 

    Worksheets("PivotTable").PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields("Qtr"). _CurrentPage = QtrChosen 

End Sub
```

The code above works like a charm for me, but this code below doesn't:

```
Sub MacroModuleName()

    Dim ModulNameVariable As String

    ModulNameVariable = Worksheets("MenuSheet").Range("G3").Value

    Dim PivotTable1, PivotTable2, PivotTable3, PivotTable4, PivotTable5 As PivotTable

    Worksheets("Pivot1Sheet").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _

    "[ModulesDatabase].[Module Name].[Module Name]").ClearAllFilters

    Worksheets("Pivot1Sheet").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _

    "[ModulesDatabase].[Module Name].[Module Name]").CurrentPage = _

    ModulNameVariable


  End Sub
```

Does anybody know how to deal with this problem? Any insight or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Also, Dim PivotTable1, PivotTable2, PivotTable3, PivotTable4, PivotTable5 As PivotTable   declares only the last as a PivotTable, the others are variants. You need to declare the type of each one explicitly i.e. Dim PivotTable1 As PivotTable etc......

Comment: Do the pivottables come off the same source data? You might also want to look into pivottable update events.

Comment: You can either loop all pivottables in the second sheet applying the setting or, if you can link the pivottables then simply update one and have the others [sync](https://blog.gbrueckl.at/2012/04/synchronizing-pivottable-filters/). Other links include....[Change All Pivot Tables With One Selection](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/01/03/change-all-pivot-tables-with-one-selection/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about the type of error messages you are getting you might be able to loop through all pivottables in the sheet and apply the setting as follows (assumes you will apply to all in sheet though you could exclude by testing the name of the pivot during the loop.). I am assuming the following 
`[ModulesDatabase].[Module Name].[Module Name]` is correct.

Notes:

You declared most of your pivottable variables as variants rather than as pivottable as mentioned in comment.

I don't see a combobox shown in your code so I don't know if you have a linked cell which then indexes into a list and returns a value to the Range("G3")? I am also unclear on how you trigger this. Have you tied it to a button?

I would recommend looking at the links I gave in the comments regarding synchronizing pivot tables and PivotTableUpdate() events as this might be more efficient than looping each pivottable and applying a setting.

```
Sub MacroModuleName()

    Dim ModulNameVariable As String

    ModulNameVariable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MenuSheet").Range("G3").Value

    Dim pvt As PivotTable

    For Each pvt In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot1Sheet")

          pvt.PivotFields("[ModulesDatabase].[Module Name].[Module Name]").ClearAllFilters
          pvt.PivotFields("[ModulesDatabase].[Module Name].[Module Name]").CurrentPage = _
          ModulNameVariable

    Next pvt

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Qharr, thanks so much for your help, really appreciate that. I tried your code and it gave me an error message: "Runtime Errror '438': Object doesn't support this property of method." My previous error was: "Unable to set CurrentPage property of PivotField class." As I look at the code again, it dawned upon me that the problem might be because my PivotTables were created via PowerPivot. Any ideas as to how I can accomplish the task above with PowerPivot? Thanks so much again!

Comment: Are the pivots built off the same data source? If so consider using a slicer?

Comment: Did this help at all?

Comment: Hi Qharr, thanks for your concern and sorry for the late reply! I didn't use a slicer since these PivotTables are linked to a Combobox in the main page of a dashboard. Anyway, after a lot of trials and errors I think the problem is the incorrectly linked databases or alike and I tried incorporating your code into mine, and that worked well! So thanks a lot again for your help, really appreciate that!